# How to change row background color dynamic in MVC view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a dynamic table like:

```
<tbody>
  <% foreach (var item in Model)
   {
  %>
      <tr>
       ......
      </tr>
  <% } %>
</tbody>
```

Then I want to change the row background color to different for neighbor row:

```
<tbody>
     <% int i = 0;
        foreach (var item in Model)
        {
     %>
     <%if (i++ % 2 == 0)
     { %>
       <tr style="background-color:Aqua">
     <%} else { %>
       <tr style="background-color:Fuchsia">
     <%} %>
     ....
      </tr>
  <% } %>
</tbody>
```

But it doesn't work.  Or anotther way like: `<tr style="background-color:<%...%>">`, also not work. How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not incrementing your **i** variable in the loop.

Comment: Thank you. I have modified it, but my problem is runtime error.

Comment: Here is my error message: A local variable named 'i' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'i', which is already used in a 'child' scope to denote something else

Comment: Thank you. Find out problem. i is used twice in the view.

Answer (score 0):

Incremental **i** variable same this code.

```
Model.IndexOf(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap class - `table table-striped`

e.g.-

```
<table class="table table-striped">
.....
</table>
```